# Rspec for building nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have following code snippet in my `CompaniesController`

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @company  = Company.new
    @company.employees.build
  end
```

In my Rspec how can I check that `build` method is called inside `new` action?

I tried something like this

```
expect(assigns(:company).employees).to have_received(:build)
```

but I am getting following error message:

```
#<Employee::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fe2ca2141e8> expected to have received build, but that object is not a spy or method has not been stubbed.
```

Do I need to stub employee first?

## Update:

Rspec for new action

```
describe "GET 'new'" do

before { get :new }

it 'assigns @domain_name' do
  expect(assigns(:domain_name)).to eq(request.host)
end

it 'assigns @company' do
  expect(assigns(:company)).to be_a_new(Company)
end

it 'renders the new template' do
  expect(response).to render_template('new')
end
```

end

Thanks

Comment: could you please post your test block for the **new** method?

Comment: @Emu I have updated my question with test block for new method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
before { expect_any_instance_of(Company.new.employees.class).to receive(:build) }
```

Comment: Thanks works great. There is extra bracket ' } ' in your answer. I am not able to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

How about checking the outcome instead of checking whether the method call took place?

```
it 'builds an employee on @company' do
  expect(assigns(:company).employees.length).to eq(1)
  # and/or
  expect(assigns(:company).employees.first).to be_a_new(Employee)
end
```

Comment: feels more like a model testing rather than controller testing.